# IE10 do not receive events from ActiveX object using IE10 'Document Mode'

Tags: debugging, events, activex, internet-explorer-10, forward-compatibility

IE10 do not get ActiveX events using Standard document mode, on previous versions of IE same control fires events, and IE is notified when they are triggered.

I use a code with this pattern to handle the events:
'alert(true);'

'true' is only alerted when using IE9 and lower Document Modes

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  I've discovered that it's not related to the Document Mode but to the Browser Mode.  In Browser Mode IE9 (or earlier) or IE10 Compatibility View, it works fine (with Document Mode Standards).  But in plain IE10 mode, events are not received.  In the ActiveX control, the invoke calls are getting S_OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution that worked for me in here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/34a8d6e5-c14a-48ef-af49-a9f970697564/are-activex-control-events-still-supported-in-ie10-standards-mode?forum=ieextensiondevelopment

It demonstrates using 'eval':

eval('function ActivexID::OnLoad(msg) { alert(msg); }');

Answer (score 0):

Here are some reasons:

- [ActiveX filtering](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/02/28/activex-filtering-for-consumers.aspx) is enabled via [group policy](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2522815) or [user settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg699456)
- ActiveX is being blocked due to an [obsolete certificate](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/06/13/windows-internet-explorer-block-rsa-key-shorter-than-1024-bits.aspx?Redirected=true)
- IE10 is running in Metro mode